# FileUtils.copyURLToFile not working with low internet speeds

Tags: android, download, apache-commons

I am using apache commons-io `FileUtils` for downloading a file into android device from given url.

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(urlString), tempFolderFile)
```

This works very well under normal internet speeds, but does not work at all under 2G internet speed (1kB/sec).

Is this a limitation with apache commons-io library or is there a way to achieve download with this library ?

Comment: Any errors? Exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffersize will not impact much. It should be maintained within safe limit, library will take care of it. 2G internet speeds vary from 10-20 kbps. Make sure timeout is sufficiently high to download the file.